# Concatenation order and performance under Lazy Evaluation in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, concatenation, lazy-evaluation, associativity

Consider the following two execution orders：

```hs
a ++ (b ++ c)
```

and

```hs
(a ++ b) ++ c
```

Why is the first execution order faster than the second?

I'm new to Haskell, hoping for a detailed explanation, thanks!

Comment: How do you know it's faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When fully evaluating the result of `x ++ y`, you must pay:

1. The cost of fully evaluating `x`.
2. The cost of fully evaluating `y`.
3. The cost of traversing `x` once while executing the `(++)` operation.

Now let's compare `a ++ (b ++ c)` and `(a ++ b) ++ c`. Let's write the cost of evaluating `a` as CA (and similarly CB, CC), and the cost of traversing `a` as TA (and similarly TB, TC). Then the cost of fully evaluating `a ++ (b ++ c)` is:

1. The cost of `a`, CA.
2. The cost of `b ++ c`, which is

   1. CB
   2. CC
   3. One traversal of `b`, TB.
3. TA

This is a grand total of CA+CB+CC+TA+TB. Now, for `(a ++ b) ++ c`:

1. The cost of `a ++ b`, which is

   1. CA
   2. CB
   3. TA
2. CC
3. One traversal of `a ++ b`, which is TA+TB.

This is a grand total of CA+CB+CC+2*TA+TB. Compared to the other order, there is an extra traversal of `a`, for an extra cost of TA, so this order is more expensive.

I leave it to the reader to try longer chains and start figuring out the pattern. In short, the bad association gives a quadratic amount of traversal as it redoes all the traversals it has already done, plus one more, at each invocation of `(++)`, while the good association traverses each list at most once.

Comment: So that’s probably the reason why `++` is `infixr` and not `infixl`!

Comment: @MikaelF Yes, it definitely is.